# If I have an outstanding medical bill in America, can I go back there?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, health, denial-of-entry

In 2007 I was in Texas when I fell really sick. I was rushed to hospital because my throat closed up and walked out with a medical bill of $1,200. I had travel insurance but they where being difficult in paying the claim, so I never did. I am travelling to Hawaii in November this year and I am worried that I will not be allowed into the country due to my outstanding bill?

Comment: I'd assume you might just have a bad credit rating now, or debt collectors after you at worst, but it'd be a civil matter? Govt hospital or private?

Comment: I won't add a proper answer tho as I'm no expert on this.

Comment: @MarkMayo I'm not sure of what hospital it was in. No my credit rating is fine, it has never come up on anything. I live in Australia and have travelled a bit since then and there have been no issues getting a visa or being allowed into the country, however I have not tried going back to the states or any countries under their control.

Comment: Do you know the name of the hospital? Could look it up online to see what type.

Comment: The feds are not bill collectors so I really doubt there will be a problem with a civil matter like that. Of course, if you're carrying a suitcase full of counterfeit NFL jerseys that's another matter. More seriously, they are supposed to evaluate whether you have the likelihood of becoming a public charge, but if you have sufficient funds and insurance for your current trip, there should not be an issue, even if they had a way of knowing. But why didn't you pay the bill yourself, even if your insurance wouldn't?

Comment: More then likely this bill have been paid by the state or written off as a loss by the hospital.  Of course you can check to see if there are any outstanding warrants for you but I doubt that there will be any.  Though stranger things have been known to happen: http://www.nakedcapitalism.com/2010/06/jail-for-unpaid-debt-a-reality-in-six-states-strategic-default-pushback-watch.html

Answer (score 5):

I know about people who did similar things due to insufficient insurance. No problem for you, especially in different state.

This is one of the reasons your bill was so high: **hospital in USA is required to provide emergency care,** but then is let high and dry to collect for provided services. You have to pay not only for you, but for many other people who choose not to pay (or could not afford to pay) for the services hospital was required to provide.

Get insurance from different company this time, and let internet know about that bad insurance so people can avoid it.